# Upgrading the JRE used by ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, java

I have a ColdFusion 8.1 application. It gets heavy use and I see jrun.exe getting very high memory usage in the task manager. This is a 32-bit windows 2003 server. When Jrun gets around a gig of memory usage ColdFusion will stop responding at some point. The logs are a little vague, but I start to see garbage collection and heap errors in the ColdFusion log. I assume that the JRE is running out of memory.

I have the max JVM heap set to 1.2gig. After some experimenting, this seemed to be the biggest amount I could allocate and still have ColdFusion start ok. I realize that going to 64-bit might solve the problem, but that is not an option at this time.

I am considering upgrading the JRE (it is at v6.x dated pre-2008, though I don't know the exact version. I am using the JRE that came with ColdFusion 8.1. Has anyone gone through this? I assume it's just a matter of installing the new JRE and pointing ColdFusion to the new JRE directory in the ColdFusion server settings.

tia
don

Comment: I don't think upgrading JDK will not give u any better performance.. since it is still limited to ~1.2GB heap as you said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's **EXTREMELY** easy to do.

1) download the [Java SE Development Kit](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u13-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) and install it like normal.

2) open up the **jmv.config** for cf in a text editor, located in **c:\coldfusion8\runtime\bin**

3) comment out the existing **java.home** line with a by putting a **"#"** at the beginning of the line add a new **java.home** line below it pointing to your jvm installation.

As an example, my java.home and jvm.config look like this:
**java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre**

4) restart the CF services.

As a bonus, you can running [JavaRa](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/JavaRa-Download-97297.html) and free up some space by deleting all the old versions of the JRE.

Comment: Some tips: if ColdFusion won't start after you change java.home in jvm.config, try running {CF_HOME}/bin/cfstart.bat on the command line to see what's wrong. In my case, to get CF 9.0.2 working with Java 7 I had to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package to get MSVCR100.dll. ¯\\(°_o)/¯

Answer (score 2):

Adobe has a Knowledge Base that covers issues like this. Check out http://www.adobe.com/go/2d547983 for instructions.

Sean Corfield has an article that provides some info on using Java 6 with ColdFusion 8 here:
http://corfield.org/blog/index.cfm/do/blog.entry/entry/Java_6_and_ColdFusion_8

As long as you install 1.6.0_10 or greater, you should be fine. You might check out ColdFusionBloggers.org from time to time in case other JVM issues come to light in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether or not you were using the stand-alone server instance or a multi-server configuration. If you're getting a heavy volume of traffic and have a dual core machine with a lot of physical memory, I would consider looking into the multi-server set-up for CF8 and putting together a cluster with load balancing. This will help to distribute your traffic across several instances of CF8 and, assuming you have a beefy server, make better use of the physical resources that you have available.

-Rick

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving Java 7. Java 7 has the G1 Garbage collector which is better at memory deallocation.

If you are having out of memory issues it could be because

functions are not using `var` or `local` scope

`<cfdump>` is used in a production system

Sessions are too large or are not set to expire in a reasonable amount of time

Queries are way too large `SELECT *` can cause that.

Excessive number Query of Queries.

The site is connecting to a slow database. Resources are held until the DB returns data

DSN has the data buffer set to more than 64k