# ColdFusion 8 scheduler not rescheduling task

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-8

I have just done a clean install of CF8 on a Windows 2000 machine. I have a scheduled task I need to run every 15 minutes on this machine, and the machine does little else.

The task is set up as normal through CF admin, but for some reason, when the task takes about 5 minutes to run it will complete fine (I can see this from debug output and from cfstat) but the scheduler will not reschedule the task.

The scheduling log shows that the task started to execute, but not entry that it was rescheduled. Eg:

```
[ProcessRecords] Executing at Wed May 20 10:30:00 BST 2009
```

I have been over my server timeouts. I have NO timeout in CF admin and this particular script has a `<cfsetting requesttimeout="43200" />` tag set. There are no exceptions in the console logging. The last bit of console logging is the very last debug statement in my .cfm template.

I do notice that task that run in a shorter time, say for example under a minute, will reschedule as normal.

Has anyone come across a problem like this before?

I'm baffled. Any and all replies are appreciated!

Cheers,
Ciaran

Comment: This fix I have found for this is to add in a few <cfflush /> tags to the template being called. If the template is long running then this seems to let the scheduler know to reschedule the job when it completes. Without the <cfflush /> it just doesn't reschedule even thought the request ends. Very strange.

Answer (score 4):

not for nothing, but i've never seen anything like this with cf8. are you sure that you have the latest hotfix and jvm installed? this might have been something in cf8 that was fixed in 8.01.

[hotfix 2 for cf8.01](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403781.html)

[list of all hotfixes and updates for cf8.01](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402604.html#CF801)

[hotfix 3 for cf8](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403070.html)

[list of all hotfixes and updates for cf8](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402604.html#CF8)

[latest jvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)

[upgrade instruction for jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798491/upgrading-the-jre-used-by-coldfusion/798852#798852)

If you suspect that it's an uncaught exception causing the issue, then might I suggest logging portions of the process. Case in point, I had a similar problem with a scheduled task where it would just bottom out for no reason (never had the reschedule problem though). What I ended up doing to diagnose the problem was use cflog to write out portions of the process as they completed. This particular task too about 4 minutes to complete but ran through about 200 portions (it was a mass emailer for a bunch of clients).

I logged the when the portion started and completed along with how log it took. By doing so, i could see what portion would trip up the whole process and knew where to focus my attention.

Comment: +1 I had this issue and hotfix solved it for me if I recall correctly

Comment: I have CF updated to v. 8,0,1,195765, so I presume that includes this hotfix? Or should I still look at getting this hotfix installed?

Comment: unfortunately you can't tell by just looking at the version number. you'll have to look in your coldfusion\lib\updates directory to see if the file chf8010002.jar exists. also make sure your Java Version is 1.6.0_13

Comment: also, just wanted to point out that in my answer i only provided the link for the cf8 hotfix and NOT cf8.01 which are DIFFERENT! i updated my answers with link for both as well as the listing for all hotfixes and updates for both versions. remember that cf8 and cf8.01 have different updates and hotfixes and can easily get confusing.

Comment: @rip747 - thanks for that clarification. Will try that hot-fix shortly.

Comment: Initially it looked like those updates might have worked but, alas the same issues are back. I suspect CF is swallowing an exception as nothing is showing up in any logs. May have to use a different non CF approach which isn't very satisfactory :)

Comment: @rip747 - Thanks for the feedback - I have tried this debug approach and my code finishes every time with no exceptions. When I say there might be a swallowed exception, I'm thinking in the scheduler code itself. This is very frustrating as the problem only seems to occur sometimes. I'll keep thinking about it however.